# Difference between "garbage" and "trash"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns, american-english

What's the difference between *garbage* and *trash*? Is the difference significant?

Comment: Wait what, no love for *rubbish*, *litter*, *junk*, *refuse*..?

Comment: @RegDwight
Well, this question is sorta specific to AmE
I'm not hating on BrE! :D

Comment: Ah yes. Mkay. I took the liberty of adding the AmE tag.

Comment: Garbage is what you program into a computer. Trash is what you try to keep your daughter from dating.

Comment: This is highly dependent on locale and culture.  In some cities trash and garbage must be separated, in others, not.  Where they aren't separated the choice of terms is likely to be based on family background as much as anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the saying "one person's trash is another person's treasure" helps answer this question. *Trash* more often has the meaning of something discarded, whereas *garbage* more often carries the meaning of true refuse, often food waste. Of course, food waste can be a treasure to a gardener working on a compost pile, but I'm speaking generally here. It's not a very significant distinction, and the terms are often used interchangeably, but there are instances when they are not synonymous.

This excerpt from a 1986 *Orlando Sentinel* article titled "[Trash Vs. Garbage: Any Big Difference?](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/1986-05-04/news/0220100267_1_garbage-trash-bunch-of-stuff)" supports this general distinction in meaning:

> There was a little note stuck to the can. It said, in essence, that my refuse hadn't been picked up because -- and I quote -- ''trash and garbage had been mixed.''
>
> I hate making mistakes like that. I didn't close the cover on a book of matches before striking. It was weeks before I got over the guilt.
>
> I called Georgia Waste Systems, where I have my trash/garbage account, to apologize. They were very nice and said a lot of people make the same mistake I did and they were not planning a lawsuit.
>
> As long as I had somebody on the phone who could explain, I asked, ''What is the difference between trash and garbage?''
>
> ''Garbage,'' the woman said, ''are things that come from the bathroom or kitchen.''
>
> ''You mean like bread you leave out for months and green things start growing on it?'' I asked.
>
> ''Precisely,'' she said.
>
> ''Trash,'' she continued, ''is basically anything else. We do not pick up leaves, for instance, or old furniture or boxes of materials that were collected when somebody cleaned out their attic.''

Comment: Probably worth saying that "trash and garbage had been mixed." won't be widely understood; the distinction isn't firm enough for that phrase to make sense. Normally you'd say something like "food and non-food waste had been mixed".

Answer (score 6):

The distinction my grandparents made was that they burned their trash but not their garbage. If this was ever the general rule, it no longer is.

UPDATE: There's some evidence for this definition in the [1896 Webster's Collegiate Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=4aEMAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=webster%27s+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZzDGT_6QGIKy8QTq64nPBg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=trash&f=false), although there definition (2) doesn't include waste paper, which my grandparents definitely included in *trash*.

> Trash: 1. That which is worthless or useless; rubbish; refuse. 2. Esp., loppings and leaves of trees, bruised sugar cane, etc. 3. A worthless person.
>   Garbage: Offal; refuse animal or vegetable matter from a kitchen; hence, anything worthless or loathsome.

Comment: can't you technically burn anything?  or do you mean things that are flammable, per se?

Comment: Trash was the stuff they disposed of by burning themselves. Garbage was the stuff they paid somebody to haul away.

Comment: That's interesting, never heard that one before.

Comment: that's interesting; i suppose most people don't burn any waste nowadays, though.

Comment: @bcc32: It's probably illegal to burn your waste nowadays, which is why I commented that this may not still be the rule. It also may not have been the generally accepted definition ... I don't know.

Comment: This is interesting. In many places, yard waste burning is still common and legal within strict guidelines like [these](http://www.lehighfd.com/life-safety-division/burning-regulations/). Notice there that there is some effort put into defining yard _trash_ and distinguishing it from other "trash." It's assumed, however, that _garbage_ is illegal to burn. I think in most of these ordinances, you'll find an effort to switch to the term _yard waste_, probably to avoid the ambiguity of _trash_.

Answer (score 6):

I am almost 80 years old.  When I was a child, I remember we had two collections, trash, and garbage.  The trash was cans, paper, etc.  Garbage was what we used to put into a strainer in our sinks before we washed dished (garbage disposers hadn't been invented yet?)  The trash went to a "sanitary-fill" where piles of trash were burned, and then metal cans were extracted with a electro-magnet.  Then what was left was pushed over into a canyon and covered with dirt.  The garbage was given to places that raised hogs and pigs.  Also, the garbage can was a small container with a lid to keep off the flies, but most of the trash containers were not covered.  Well, that is the way it was seventy years ago!

Answer (score 4):

*Garbage* is organic (*e.g.* food scraps, etc.).
*Trash* is inorganic (*e.g.* bottles, cans, etc.).

Comment: A garbage-collector friend of mine specified the distinction as "garbage is wet, trash is dry", and as explained further is basically this organic/manufactured distinction.

Comment: Who says? Is this a regional dialect?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that "Trash" is more of a slang term.  I suppose they are both an alternative for "refuse".  They are somewhat contextual, as well.  For example:

> That outfit makes you look trashy.

In this sense, the word trash is used to imply the wearer of the clothing appears to be disheveled, careless, or provocative.  Personally, I wouldn't say,

> That outfit makes you look like garbage.

The context has shifted to imply the wearer now resembles a large pile of refuse.  I seriously doubt this is the case.  I suppose they may be modelling the "Derelict" line of fashion clothing, featured in the *Zoolander* movie.